# Replacment ceiling fan capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I have a ceiling fan that only operates on low speed.  I am fairly positive that it is a bad capacitor.

It is a five wire capacitor that has 2.5uF/250V, 4uF/250V, and 4uf/300V.  I can't seem to find a replacement capacitor with the same capacitance and voltage ratings.  What (if any) degree of tolerance could I expect from this type of capacitor.  Can I replace it with another one that has different specs?

Comment: A picture says a thousand words.

Comment: A *five wire* capacitor? Yeah, I'd like to see that picture too.

Comment: If you mean it has five wires coming out of it, it might imply that there are multiple capacitors inside and you select only one. Or it could mean four of those are shorted to parallel all the capacitors and use it as one big one. Again, a picture would be better.

Comment: I'm in the middle a ceiling fan rabbit hole and feel like I should add some info here for any future readers like me. This "5-wire" cap is 3 caps.  Two of the wires(grey probably) are the common.   The one that says 4uF300V is likely a red wire.   This one goes to the fan winding and not the speed switch.  The other two go to the switch and the switch chooses one or both(in parallel) to place in *series* with the the red one.   High speed is the red alone(4uF), so you don't want anything higher than that.  There is no safety risk if off by .5 or 1 for the others, just won't match the old speed

Answer (score 2):

Voltage and capacitance ratings are important.
You can go higher than needed voltage rating. for example if you need  @20V rating capacitor, you can use  30V cap since the needed voltage is below 30V. Also make sure you follow original capacitance rating.